# How to remove page title from the post title link?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been playing around with the php to try and get the post title to link to the correct post but now it keeps adding the page name on the end.

```
<h6><a href="<?php the_permalink($this_post->ID); ?>" title="<?php 
the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title($this_post->post_title); ?></a></h6>
```

Here is a link to the page so you can see what I mean properly - http://www.city-perks.co.uk/discounts/

Comment: The question is still unclear. Seems like WP is doing the right thing. What do you want the question and answer to achieve?

Comment: So the title now links to the correct post but it adds the word Discounts onto the end of each title and I can't remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
     if ($cmb_listing_layout == '3') 
     { 
         sprintf('<h6>%s</h6>', esc_attr($this_post->ID)); 
     } 
?>
```

If you want to get title another page, you need use `get_the_title( $id_page )` function.

Comment: As the complete idiot I am, I pasted the wrong line of code in the question. I've updated the question now so maybe it makes a little more sense.

Comment: Thank you, I have the correct title showing, it just adds the word Discount onto the end of it for some reason.

Comment: @RobDunn `the_title` returns the title of the current page. [Displays or returns the unescaped title of the current post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title)

Comment: Sorry I'm not 100% confident with php. This is what I thought would work but it's still showing the same issue.
    <h6><a href="<?php the_permalink($this_post->ID); ?>" title="<?php 
    get_the_title($id_page); ?>"><?php the_title($this_post->post_title); ?
    ></a></h6>

Comment: @RobDunn And this not working? I try to help you, but you say that you are right.

Comment: It shows up the right post title but then adds Discounts after it. I'm not saying I am right, I am saying I can't get it working properly. 
For example the post title should be "20% Off TeamSport Karting" but it displays "20% Off TeamSport KartingDiscounts"

Comment: @RobDunn you need use get_the_title( $id_page ) function.

Comment: <h6><a href="<?php the_permalink($this_post->ID); ?>" title="<?php get_the_title($id_page); ?>"><?php get_the_title($this_post->post_title); ?></a></h6>

I have just put this code in but now the title has completely disappeared. I'm not sure where to put the function

Comment: @RobDunn Man please read manual about this function. Why you try to pass label? You need to pass ID